Where was the machine learning concept of pseudo-dimension introduced?
I've been looking into the topic of pseudo-dimension in learning theory (e.g. here) and I am trying to find out where it was first introduced and first used in learning theory. The earliest reference I could find is Pollard's Lecture notes on Empirical Processes but I'm wondering if anyone knows where it was first introduced (or, if it was first introduced here).
(P.S. I asked this on math stack exchange and the commenter suggested I ask here).

The pseudo-dimension is a generalization to functions of the Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension for sets introduced in their On the Uniform Convergence of Relative Frequencies of Events to Their Probabilities (1971). It also generalizes Dudley's algebraic dimension from Dudley's Central Limit Theorems for Empirical Measures, and Pollard's methods go back to Dudley.
The pseudo-dimension was introduced by Pollard earlier than in the OP 1990 link, in his Convergence of Stochastic Processes (1984), some authors call it Pollard's pseudo-dimension. Haussler explicitly attributes it to him in section 4 of Decision theoretic generalizations of the PAC model for neural net and other learning applications (1992):

"In this section we look at one way that bounds on the covering numbers appearing in Theorem 2 can be obtained. This technique, due to Pollard (1984), who extended methods from Dudley (1978), is based on certain intuitions from combinatorial geometry. It generalizes the techniques based
on the Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension used in Blumer et al. (1989), which apply only to $\{0, 1 \}$-valued functions... Thus the pseudo dimension
generalizes the Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension to arbitrary classes of real-valued functions. The pseudo dimension also generalizes the algebraic notion of the dimension of a vector space of real-valued functions (Dudley, 1978).  [...] There are many other ways that the VC dimension can be generalized to
real-valued functions (Natarajan, 1989a, 1989b; Pollard, 1984; Vapnik,
1989; Dudley, 1987). Dudley (1987) compares several such generalizations,
albeit in a different context. The generalization we have proposed here, the pseudo dimension, is a minor variant of the notion used by Pollard (1984)
to define classes of real-valued functions of polynomial discrimination, called VC-subgraph classes in Dudley (1987). The pseudo dimension will be used in the form defined above in Pollard's new book (Pollard, 1990).  [...]  Using techniques that go back to Dudley (1978), Pollard has obtained a
beautiful theorem bounding the metric dimension of $(\mathbf{F}, d_{L^1(P)})$ by $\dim_P(\mathbf{F})$
for any probability measure $P$ on $Z$. Actually this result is much stronger in that it gives explicit bounds on the packing number for $\mathbf{F}$ using $d_{L^1(P)}$
balls of radius $\varepsilon$. Since packing numbers are closely related to covering
numbers, these bounds can then be used with
Theorem 2 to obtain uniform convergence results for empirical estimates of
functions in $\mathbf{F}$."


Thank you, this is great! I'm curious how the various notions of pseudo dimension relate to each other. With what you've given me, I think I can read and understand it!
